# xamarin.forms: image is rendered differently on android than on ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am building this view currently:

[image]

This is a snapshot of the ios render, the code simply is:

```
<StackLayout>
                       <Image Source="img_logo"/>
                   </StackLayout>
```

But Android is not quite the same:

[image]

I tried everything, giving it verticaloptions, horizontaloptions, changing the aspect to everything, the image is never displayed as it is in ios. It is either clipped, or loses its original aspect ratio. I dont know what else to try here and why I have to do anything in the first place. Please tell me the atributes I need to use...

Answer (score 0):

This code is expected to be rendered differently in some cases.

It is very important what is the target screen density of the image in your platform project. If it is different then obviously it will be rendered at a different size with the code above.

If you want to achieve the same look set the `Width` or `Height` property or both. Assuming that the container allows those values (that it is big enough) it will look exactly the same then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust adjust the size of the image according to the space ratio of different views on the page, you can use `Grid` to achieve this.

You can set the width to `Star` or a special value.

For more about this, you can check [rows-and-columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns).

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Logo -->
       <Image Grid.Row="0"
       Source="test.png"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      />

        <!-- Sign In Button -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Sign In " />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```